# Automate input to a binary I can't modify

Tags: c++, input, debian

I would like to automate input to a binary I can't modify, what are the different way? I'm working on Debian.

For example, if there is a scanf in a C++ program, the user has to type some text, I would like to preset this text without having to use my keyboard.

For example if a program contains:

```
printf("What's your name ?")
scanf("%s", &name)
printf("How old are you")
scanf("%d", &age)
```

I would do something like program x4rkz 99, without typing x4rkz at the scanf, but before so that no human as to do anything during the process.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I edited, I want to fill the scanf without the me typing while the program is running. I want to type it before so that it fills automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat <<EOT | yourbin
x4rkz
99
EOT
```

Comment: Apparently you have to remove the space after the '|'.